# Angular dynamically include html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to include HMTL for Bootstrap modal on click but I cannot get it to work.

In my controller I have this code:

```
  $scope.onFollowingClick = function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        $scope.isFollowingModal = true;
        $('#FollowingModal').modal('toggle');
    };
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-if="isFollowingModal">
    <div class="modal modal-alternate fade" ng-include="'/Templates/Modals/Public/ModalFollowing.html'" id="FollowingModal"> </div>
</div>
```

And when I click button nothing happens ("clicked" is logged in console), in browser  when I inspect element, I only see:

```
<!-- ngIf: isFollowingModal -->
```

And no network request to fetch ModalFollowing.html is logged.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're trying to use a jQuery plugin inside an AngularJS controller -- it's possible, just not recommended.  Try an AngularJS alternative: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal or http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals.

Comment: even if request is made, you aren't accounting for asynchronous loading before trying to activate the modal. That's what directives are used for

Comment: @charlietfl what you are saying is completely true but this doesn't explain why request isn't made :/

Comment: Use $watch in scope it will help to solve your problem

Comment: @SiddharthPandey can you please explain more ? I don't see how $watch will help me with this case ?

Comment: @hyperN Sorry without watch only its working check this plunker code am i getting correct your you have different problem http://plnkr.co/edit/n7idBSY5RKoI7UT5IzRH?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go this way, using `$http` service is really helpful even though `ngInclude` fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment.

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function() {
  $http
    .get('/Templates/Modals/Public/ModalFollowing.html')
    .success(function(response) {
      $('modal')
        .html(response)
        .modal('show');
    });
}
```

And never forget about async :P

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll check it when I come home :)

Comment: I tried your solution, and it partially worked, HTML was injected, and modal opened but for some reason controller doesn't work (and it is called inside html)

Comment: It won't work, because you have to compile that again using `$compile`. Check the angular docs for that :P